# Powershell SNMP converting IP Address: Getting wrong value

Tags: powershell, snmp

How do I properly convert an IP Address gotten via OleSNMP to a useable value?

I'm trying to write a Powershell script to query devices with SNMP and then display the data. Stuff works fine for simple types, but I'm having problems with the IP Addresses (and MAC addresses, but let's stick to IP for now)

Here's what I have (simplified to the problem space):

```
param ($ipaddr='10.1.128.114', $community='Public')

$snmp = New-Object -ComObject oleprn.OleSNMP
$snmp.open($ipaddr, $community)

$result = $snmp.get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.1.10.1.128.114")
$enc = [system.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$bytes = $enc.GetBytes($result)
write-host( "bytes:" + $bytes)
```

Which outputs:

`bytes:10 1 63 114`

When I expected

`bytes:10 1 128 114`

For contrast, the snmp-get outputs:

```
$ snmpget 10.1.128.114 -c Public -v2c -On .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.1.10.1.128.114
.1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.1.10.1.128.114 = IpAddress: 10.1.128.114
```

And yes, I realize that in my final script I'll have to walk the table instead of using a direct "get" but I need to fix my parsing first.

Comment: What is the raw data in ```$result```? Perhaps it's not ASCII encoding?

Comment: Ah, yeah, ```63``` is ```?```, which is what you get with the ASCII encoding when you try to encode a character outside the valid range. And ```128``` is outside the valid range...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the ASCII encoding substitutes characters outside its valid range with a question mark `?`, which is ASCII character 63.

More info is available in the documentation for [ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.asciiencoding.getbytes?view=net-6.0) - search for "?" and you'll find this:

> ASCIIEncoding does not provide error detection. Any Unicode character greater than U+007F is encoded as the ASCII question mark ("?").

Note, 0x7F is 127, so since `[char] 128` is outside this range, it's being converted to the byte equivalent of `?` (which is `63`) when you call `GetBytes`.

Your code is basically doing this this:

```
$result = ([char] 10) + ([char] 1) + ([char] 128) + ([char] 114)

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$bytes = $encoding.GetBytes($result)
$bytes
# 10
# 1
# 63 (i.e. "?")
# 114
```

You need to use an encoder which will convert characters higher than 0x7F into the equivalent bytes - something like iso-8859-1 seems to work:

```
$result = ([char] 10) + ([char] 1) + ([char] 128) + ([char] 114)

$encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")
$bytes = $encoding.GetBytes($result)
$bytes
# 10
# 1
# 128
# 114
```

Comment: This is it. I'm usually in the C world where encodings don't matter as much so I never deal with "real" ASCII and always the "Extended" variant that I didn't even think of that.

Trying to decode as UTF-8 ended up making a right mess of things (More bytes?!?) as I'm guessing it hits a control char.